# Using the Interval with Operators (RxJava)

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to make a network request every 1/3 seconds and wait 3 seconds before onComplete method. How do I do that? my code below waits 3 seconds before emitting items, and it's not what I want.

```
    disposable = Observable
            .interval(0, 334, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .skipLast(9)
            .take(postsCount + 9)
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Long number) {
                    // Code in onNext method
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    // Code in onError method
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                  // Code in onComplete method
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't sleep but use composition with the desired delay:

```
Observable.intervalRange(0, postCount, 0, 334, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .concatWith(Observable.empty().delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    ... // react to each tick
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if you want to `skipLast` 9 items, RxJava should collect 9 items first and then it can know which are 'last 9 items'. I think you can simply sleep 3000 ms `onComplete`.

```
Observable.interval(0, 334, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .take(postsCount)
        .doOnComplete { Thread.sleep(3000) }
        .doOnNext { println(it) }
        .doOnComplete { println("completed") }
        .blockingSubscribe()
```